# create time stamp for datainsert method

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a cell array. One of the column is full of dates, currently in the format `'yyyy-mm-dd'`. I get an error message from using the `datainsert` method saying

> "Unable to insert element in row 1 column 3, 2014-02-07. Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]"

The dates are already in the format yyyy-mm-dd. When I try to convert them to the above format the line below does not work? The error message is `"Unrecognized month format.  Format string: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss."`

```
export_full(:,3) = cellstr(datestr(export_full(:,3), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'))';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `m` could be `month` or `minute`, you should use `mm` for month and `MM` for minute in format strings.  Matlab will accept the use of all lowercase for dates and all uppercase for times (e.g. HH:MM:SS).

Here's something relevant from the help on `datainsert`:

> If data is a cell array containing MATLAB dates, times, or timestamps,
>   the dates must be date strings of the form yyyy-mm-dd, times must be
>   time strings of the form HH:MM:SS, and timestamps must be strings of
>   the form yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF. null entries must be empty strings
>   and any NaNs in the cell array must be converted to empty strings
>   before calling datainsert.

So if your date strings are already `yyyy-mm-dd` they should be accepted - you might want to check you don't have any stray NaN values.

Comment: I've just run xSum = sum(isnan(cell2mat(export_full(3))))

xSum =

     0   So I can see there are no NAN's in my data. I've converted my date string correctly using the HH:MM:SS instead of hh:mm:ss

Comment: export_full(3) or export_full(:,3)?  What is the actual content of "row 1 column 3"? (presuming that is the location in your cell array that is make it choke)

Comment: the new error message is Error using database/datainsert (line 132)
Unable to complete insert operation. The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol
stream is incorrect. Parameter 12 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the
source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than
precision.

Comment: the content of row 1 column 3 is 2014-02-07 00:00:00, seems ok to me

Comment: New error sounds like something on the SQL side, possibly caused by something in the input data (empty string value in where there should be something numerical, for example).  The only thing I can suggest at this point is to carefully examine your cell array in MATLAB to see if any unexpected values are present.

Comment: agh been looking at the dates for so long now didn't notice there are some NANs in one of my columns which is of type double. Is there an easy way to convert NAN to sql NULL?